# Sync my specific GitLab subfolder in my git repo with another remote GitHub repo's subfolder

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a GitLab repo where I want to keep a specific folder synced with another (remote) repository.

My repo folder I want to keep synced:

`myrepo/docs`

The Remote repo:

`remoterepo/docs`

How do I make sure only my `docs` folder is being synced with someone elses `docs` folder? I want to make sure its updated every night atleast

Comment: Git doesn't do "folders" or "files". Git does *commits*. You store commits in a Git repository. Each commit is a full snapshot of every file, so that when you extract a commit (with `git checkout`) you get all the files that are in that commit. When you make a new commit (with `git commit`), the new commit is a new archive of every file. So if you want to share commits that contain only a `docs/*` set of files, make commits that contain just those files—which mostly means make a repository *out of* the files in that folder.

Comment: Note that for somewhat annoying internal reasons, Git is unable to store *folders* at all. What Git stores are files with path names that include forward slashes, e.g., `docs/doc1.txt`, `docs/doc2.txt`, and so on. Git will *create* a folder on your OS named `docs` so that your OS is happy with *files* named `docs1.txt` and so on within that folder, but to Git, these are just files named `docs/doc1.txt` and so on.

Comment: Making `docs` into its own Git repository is not the only way to deal with this problem, but it's the most direct. Your alternative is to add a lot of non-Git stuff to deal with `docs/*` files within the repository whose commit snapshots contain not only `docs/*` files, but also files such as `a*`, `b/*`, and so on. Git won't do all that for you.

Comment: The drawback to making `docs` into its own repository is, of course, that you have to convince everyone else to do the same thing. So you might want the more complicated solution just because you can't get everyone else to cooperate. That's why this is all comments, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, @torek.
The drawback of making `docs` into its own repository would indeed be a problem as the maintainers of the remote repository are people I don't know and wont even consider to convince in making the docs it's own repository.

I'm wondering if gitlab's CI pipeline could help me here in some way.

Comment: I don't know if GitLab has stuff for this. There's also `git subtree`, which takes a clever approach to everything here, but `git subtree` is not very well maintained and people keep hitting bugs in it, so I don't really *recommend* it.

Answer (score 1):

> Making docs into its own Git repository is not the only way to deal with this problem, but it's the most direct

Once you have `docs` in its own repository, updated both by you and the other repo contributors, each original repository (yours and the other) need to:

- remove docs from their repository
- add `docs` repo as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (using [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt))
- use [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote) each time you want to refresh/sync the doc subfolder (submodule)

Comment: You of course don't know how well I know this other repo owner. But I don't know this repo owner. As @torek mentioned, this is really not a solution. It wouldn't be fair to even try convince another repo owner to break up his stuff into mutliple repositories for my sake. Next up another person may come and ask to collect everything together.

Thank you for the step-by-step process though.

Comment: @jubibanna OK. I don't see a native option then: a certain amount of cooperation would be required between two different users/repositories, irrespective of the technical solution.